# How do I know which layout resource to use in my android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am an Android newbie. I want to create a listView by extending ListFragment. There are a number of predefined reources available. How do I know which one to use? Is there a place where I can get descriptions of them? I have checked on the Androd dev site, but all I get is a list of integers defining the constants.

By layout resource I mean the values I pass into my ArrayAdapter. For example in my code I have

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> playTitlesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            playTitles);
```

The pre-defined layout resource in this case is `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1`

Comment: What do you mean which resource to use?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html

Answer (score 0):

you can see the XML file `simple_list_item_activated_1.xml` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_activated_1.xml?av=f) . You can see the XML file of other resources there too.

Hope this helps. Have a nice day!